# Regex not match pattern followed by horizontal ellipsis in string

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract Twitter hashtags from text using regex in R, using `str_match_all` from the "stringr" package.

The problem is that sometimes the hashtag gets truncated, with a horizontal ellipsis character appended to the end of the text string, as shown in this example:

```
str_match_all("hello #goodbye #au…","#[[:alnum:]_+]*[^…]")[[1]]
```

I can successfully extract a list of hashtags, using the above code, but I want to *exclude* hashtags that are truncated (i.e. that have a horizontal ellipsis character).

This is frustrating as I have looked everywhere for a solution, and the above code is the best I can come up with, but clearly does not work.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: @Pascal My apologies - it is the "stringr" package

Comment: @stribizhev I am getting both substrings as in the OP's output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `regmatches` with `regexpr` and the `#[^#]+(?!…)\\b` Perl-style regex:

```
x <- "#hashtag1 notHashtag #hashtag2 notHashtag #has…"
m <- gregexpr('#[^#\\s]+(?!…)\\b', x, perl=T)
// or m <- gregexpr('#\\w+(?!…)\\b', x, perl=T)
// or m <- gregexpr('#\\S+(?!…)\\b', x, perl=T)
regmatches(x, m)
```

See [demo on CodingGround](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMamctWXh4aXVMVmM)

The regex means:

- `#` - Literal `#`
- `[^#]+` - 1 or more characters other then `#` (or `\\w+` to match alphanumerics and underscore only, or `\\S+` that will match any number of non-whitespace characters)
- `(?!…)\\b` - Match a word boundary that is not preceded by a `…`

Result of the above code execution: `[1] "#goodbye"`

Comment: Hi @stribizhev, thanks, this is on the right track. However, when I try this:

`x <- "#hashtag1 notHashtag #hashtag2 notHashtag #has…"`

`regmatches(x, regexpr('#[^#]+(?!…)\\b', x, perl=T))`

It gives the following output:

`[1] "#hashtag1 notHashtag"`

I want to match these two words: "#hashtag1" and "#hashtag2". However, it is not achieving this.

Comment: I have edited the answer. We need to either use a more precise negated character class `[^#\\s]`, or switch to `\\w` that only allows `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Or maybe even allow anything but a whitespace: [`#\\S+(?!…)\\b`](http://goo.gl/vglykN).

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm the answer works perfectly, and provides several options for fine-tuning, so I am highly appreciative. Many thanks.